# mysql- query from 3 or more tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have a moviesdb with tables

1. movies table ;
2. data table
3. persons table
4. characters table
5. Modes table

MOVIES TABLE

```
===============================================
CODE : TITLE :        DESCRIPTION       YEAR
=====================================================
1      IRON MAN 3       xxxxx          2013
2      STAR WARS        xxxxx          2013
```

PERSONS TABLE

```
===============================================
CODE : NAME:                 BIRTH_DATE
=====================================================
1      SHANE BLACK         1965:04:04 00:00:00
2      ROBERT DOWNEY       1965:04:04 00:00:00
3      Gwyneth Paltrow     1965:04:04 00:00:00
4      Don Cheadle         1965:04:04 00:00:00
```

CHARACTERS TABLE

```
===============================================
PERSON  : NAME:             MOVIE
=====================================================
2      TONY STARK          1
3      PEPPER POTTS        1
4      Col. James Rhodes   1
```

MODES TABLE

```
===============================================
CODE : NAME : 
=====================================================
1      DIRECTOR 
2      WRITER
3      ACTOR
4      CHARACTER
```

DATA TABLE

```
===============================================
CODE : MOVIE :     PERSON   MODE
=====================================================
1      1             1       1
2      1             2       3 
3      1             3       3 
4      1             4       3
```

FINAL ANSWER WOULD BE like :

```
===============================================
CODE : MOVIE TITLE :  DIRECTOR  :     ACTORS           CHARACTERS
=====================================================
1      IRON MAN 3     SHANE BLACK   Robert Downey Jr.   Tony Stark
                                    Gwyneth Paltrow     Pepper Potts
                                    Don Cheadle         Col. James
```

Thanks,

Comment: Great. Now please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17905562/edit) your question and add schemas for all your tables and relevant sample data that leads to the desired output that you've already posted.

Comment: And *poof* there's a fourth table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `inner join` or `left join` as you would with two tables:

```
select
  m.code, m.title, m.director,
  group_concat(p.name, '\n') as actors
from
  movies m
  left join data d on d.movie_code = m.code
  left join persons p on p.code = d.person_code
where
  m.code = 1
```

I'm choosing `left join` here, because I think a movie can exist without actors. Maybe your information is still incomplete, or maybe you want to store documentaries as well. By using `inner join`, a movie *must* have actors to even show up in your query.

Assuming that `persons` could contain more than just actors, they would probably have a role. Since a person can be actor in one movie, while directing another, this role would be in `data`.

You could do something like this:

```
select
  m.code, m.title,
  group_concat(case when d.role = 2 then p.name, '\n' end ) as directors,
  group_concat(case when d.role = 1 then p.name, '\n' end ) as actors
from
  movies m
  left join data d on d.movie_code = m.code
  left join persons p on p.code = d.person_code
where
  m.code = 1
```

That would give you the opportunity to store the director (or directors) of a movie in persons as well, instead of just storing their name with the movie.

[edit]
Funny, after your edit, it turns out you already have a table for the roles (modes), although you didn't describe it before. Quite confusing, but I guess that seconds query might be useful for you then. I leave it up to you to match the field names with the exact names you specified in your edit.

Comment: i havenow updated actual table schema above ;

Comment: Thanks Mr GolezTrol for the reply , Kindly please reply with updated query as i am vey new to MySql

Comment: Did you edit your entire question *again*? Still my second answer very much applies, since it shows how to get two lists of people having multiple roles. It could be characters just as well a directors. I think fixing a couple of numbers and field names should help you gain some minimal understanding of how this works.

Comment: i have found answer as  SELECT 
  `movies`.`title`,
  `movies`.`year`,
  `persons`.`name`,
  `modes`.`name`,
  `persons`.`birth_date`,
  `characters`.`name`
FROM
  `data`
  INNER JOIN `movies` ON (`data`.`movie` = `movies`.`code`)
  INNER JOIN `persons` ON (`data`.`person` = `persons`.`code`)
  INNER JOIN `modes` ON (`data`.`mode` = `modes`.`code`)
  INNER JOIN `characters` ON (`persons`.`code` = `characters`.`person`)
  AND (`characters`.`movie` = `data`.`movie`)
WHERE
  `MOVIES`.`code` = '1'

Comment: Good. That's how it works. :)